# How to pick multiple values from the table and add them dynamically for picking another column

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

```
SELECT
    AgentID,Seat1,SeatUpdated_1,Seat2,SeatUpdated_2,
    Seat3,SeatUpdated_3,nTimesSeatChanged,
    DATEDIFF(MS,(F.SeatUpdated_1),(F.SeatUpdated_3)) AvgTime
FROM ##final F
```

Now I have to pick `SeatUpdated_3` in the `diff` function based on column `nTimesSeatChanges`.

If it have value 2 for any agent, the selected column should be `SeatUpdated_2`

Comment: please add sample input and expected output

Comment: have you tried using case statement?

Comment: i'm not able to use case statement dynamically. secondly it is not hard coded that how many times seats will be updated. it can be more than 3. so i'll have to right as many as case statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the limited information would look at how you store the information first of all. It looks like you are storing related values across column. It would be simpler to work with if you looked at storing them as rows.

Current:

```
AgentID Seat1 SeatUpdated_1 Seat2 SeatUpdated_2 Seat3 SeatUpdated_3 nTimesSeatChanged
------- ----- ------------- ----- ------------- ----- ------------- -----------------
1       11                  21    01/02/2015    31    01/03/2015    2
```

TO :

```
TableKey AgentID Seat SeatUpdated
-------- ------- ---- -----------
1        1       11   01/01/2015
2        1       12   01/02/2015
3        1       13   01/03/2015
4        2       22   02/02/2015
5        2       23   02/03/2015
```

Then work in simple queries to get the end result. I'm not an expert by any means but this is how I would approach it.

```
;
--Some sample data
WITH CTE_DATA as
(
SELECT '1' as TableKey, '1' as 'AgentID','11' as'Seat','01/01/2015' as 'SeatUpdated'
UNION
SELECT '2','1','12','01/02/2015'
UNION
SELECT '3','1','13','01/03/2015'
UNION
SELECT '4','2','22','02/02/2015'
UNION
SELECT '5','2','23','02/03/2015'
)
,

--Get Min Seat
    CTE_Min AS (
        SELECT AgentID
            ,MIN(Seat) AS min_seat
        FROM CTE_DATA
        GROUP BY AgentID
        )
--Get max seat
    ,CTE_Max AS (
        SELECT AgentID
            ,MAX(Seat) AS max_seat
        FROM CTE_DATA
        GROUP BY AgentID
        )
--Stick them together
    ,CTE_Join AS (
        SELECT Min.AgentID
            ,Min.min_seat
            ,max.max_seat
        FROM CTE_Min min
        JOIN CTE_Max max ON min.AgentID = max.AgentID
        )
--Get the date
    ,CTE_JoinDate AS (
        SELECT j.*
            ,d1.SeatUpdated AS min_date
            ,d2.SeatUpdated AS max_date
        FROM CTE_Join j
        LEFT JOIN CTE_DATA d1 ON j.AgentID = d1.AgentID
            AND j.min_seat = d1.Seat
        LEFT JOIN CTE_DATA d2 ON j.AgentID = d2.AgentID
            AND j.max_seat = d2.Seat
        )
--Work out nSeats
    ,CTE_nSeats AS (
        SELECT AgentID
            ,COUNT(1) AS nSeats
        FROM CTE_DATA
        GROUP BY AgentID
        )

--Final result set
SELECT j.*
    ,DATEDIFF(DAY, min_date, max_date) AS DIFF_Days
    ,n.nSeats
FROM CTE_JoinDate j
LEFT JOIN CTE_nSeats n ON j.AgentID = n.AgentID
```